# index is outside the bounds of the array in "decoder"

Tags: vb.net

i dont know what wrong, This is the error giving code.
"Index is outside the bounds of the array"
Its a sort of decoder it takes a string from a mysql server and decodes the data its a pretty long string , +-120 chars

```
Dim table As DataTable
        Dim row As DataRow
        Dim column As DataColumn
        For Each table In ds1.Tables
            For Each row In table.Rows
                For Each column In table.Columns
                    Dim DATAFRM As String = (row(column)).ToString


                    Dim values = DATAFRM.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Split(","c)
                    Dim a As String = values(0)
                    Dim b As String = values(1)
                    Dim c As String = values(2)
                    Dim d As String = values(3)
                    Dim e1 As String = values(4)
                    Dim f As String = values(5)
                    Dim g As String = values(6)
                    Dim h As String = values(7)
                    Dim i1 As String = values(8)
                    Dim j As String = values(9)
                    Dim k As String = values(10)
                    Dim l As String = values(11)
                    Dim m As String = values(12)
                    Dim n As String = values(13)
                    Dim o As String = values(14)
                    Dim p1 As String = values(15)
                    Dim q As String = values(16)
                    Dim r As String = values(17)
                    Dim s1 As String = values(18)


                Next column
            Next row
        Next table
```

Comment: What is does DATAFRM contain then the error happens?

Comment: SO that's 0 thru 17 .. not 18...  Figure out why the difference and if need be redim preserve Values before you assign them

Comment: That worked thanks